# open the second fancybox type iframe from a link inside the first fancybox type iframe Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, fancybox, fancybox-2

I used fancybox v2.1.5.
I have a layout_popup used to load content of these fancyboxs. Content of two fancyboxs is two view files in CodeIgniter. 
Step 1: From page I have a button to popup the first fancybox (type iframe). 
Step 2: From the first fancybox, I have a link to popup the second fancybox (type iframe). 
I finished step 1. 
Please show me how to execute step 2!
Code layout_popup:

```
<a id="addmore" class="hand-pointer" onclick="add_more();">Add more product...</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CreateFancyBox(selector, url, width, height) {
        $(selector).fancybox({
            'href': url,
            'titleShow'         : false,
            'titlePosition'     : 'none',
            'openEffect'        : 'none',
            'closeEffect'       : 'none',
            'openSpeed'         : 'fast',
            'type'              : 'iframe',
            'padding'           : 0,
            'preload'           : true,
            'width'             : width,
            'height'            : height,
            'fitToView'         : false,
            'autoSize'          : false,
        }); 
}
    function add_more() {
        var url = base_url + 'ctl_product/add_more_product';
        CreateFancyBox('a#addmore', url, '50%', 205);
    }</script>
```

From here, I click "Add more product...", popup first fancybox displays, content of first fancybox (from a view file):

```
<div style="background-color: white;">
    <form id="frmAddMoreProd" method="post" action="">
        <table id="tblAddMoreProd" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="10" width="100%" border="0">
            <tr><th><h3 style="margin-top: 0px;">Add new product</h3></th></tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Fill Product Name</td>
                <td><input class="input-short" style="width: 250px;" type="text" id="prodname" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td class="t-right">
                    <a href="#" class="cancel">Cancel</a>
                    <a id="add_next" class="b-next hand-pointer">Next</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

I want when I click link "Next" inside first fancybox, then popup the second fancybox showed. Code contain the content of the second fancybox in another view file, its code is still inside the div same as the first fancybox.

How must I do? 
I try to insert js script the same as script in layout_popup into the first fancybox, but I do not get any results.

Comment: if you are using `iframe` mode, any link inside fancybox will open still inside fancybox. You could use the method `parent.$.fancybox.update()` within from the second page to resize fancybox to fit its contents.

Answer (score 0):

The view you want to open in the iframe is actually a method inside a controller. You got the first step by building a method. For the second (iframe) step you just build another method and call the second method from the first one. I hope I said that in an understandable way :D
Here is an example:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) die ('No direct script access allowed!');

class Custom extends CI_Controller
{
    function first_method() {
        // my code
        // ...
        // echo the first view file
    }

    function second_method() {
        // my code
        // ...
        // echo the second view file
    }
}
```